# Auto generate bulk html files with minute differences

Tags: html, excel, ms-word, web-deployment

I usually type my HTML code in a word document and use mail merge in MS word to generate bulk independent word documents with minute differences.

The source for these minute differences is an Excel sheet, and then I use a third-party software (ReNamer) to convert extensions from .doc files to .html files.

Is there any better way to generate bulk independent HTML files?

Comment: If I was in your shoes, I would use the one I found on the internet that was in a language I understood.

Comment: could you provide a link to the solution you found?

Answer (score -1):

To get you started, why not export your html content written in word directly as an html file, you can do this via VBA.

```
Sub SaveHTML()

        Dim fileName
        Dim PName
        Dim FName
        Dim FType

        ' Define your file path, name and type

        PName = "C:\Temp\"
        FName = "index"
        FType = ".html"

        ' Export the file as plain text

        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
            fileName:=PName & FName & FType, _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
            LockComments:=False, _
            Password:="", _
            AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
            WritePassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
            EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
            SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
            SaveFormsData:=False, _
            SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, _
            Encoding:=1252, _
            InsertLineBreaks:=True, _
            AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
            LineEnding:=wdCRLF, _
            CompatibilityMode:=0

    End Sub
```